# Bootstrap 3, is this how to specify grid layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a form builder.  It presented the below syntax.  I was of the belief that bootstrap 3 used a column system that must add up to 12.  I see from the below it only adds up to 10.  Could some explain to be why the below is correct. Maybe I am just confused...

```
<!-- Contact Info -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="contactinfo1">
          <br>

          <form class="form-horizontal">
          <fieldset>



          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="firstname">First Name</label>  

            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md">  
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>  
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Twitter Bootstrap you can add "UPTO 12" columns that means you can include not more than 12 columns but you can involve less than 12 or actually 12 columns (NO hard-n-fast rule to make it 12 ONLY).
col-md-6 and col-md-4 adds to 10 COLUMNS.
So now you can add "col-md-2" if you want (not necessary) and this will come in the same row as the initial DIV 'col-md-4' and 'col-md-6'.
But if you add anything above 'col-md-2' i.e 'col-md-3' it will be shifted beneath.
Hope this is helpful.